# Selecting values from the database not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to retrieve some values from the database and put the onto a table with codeigniter but it does not seem to be working?

This is my model

```
function getlogrecords(){

    $query = $this->db->get('selfimpact_log');
    return $query->results();
}
```

This is my controller

```
public function abt_article() {

         $data= array();
        $query = $this->abt_db->getlogrecords();
             $data['logs']= $query;

        $this->load->view('abt_article', $data);

    }
```

The view

```
<table data-role="table" id="table-column-toggle" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive table-stroke" data-inset="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-priority="1">Statements</th>
                <th data-priority="2">Try these positive affirmations</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php if(isset($logs)): foreach($logs as $row);?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->log_id;?></td>  
                <td>I am ashamed and embarrassed that I have Postnatal Depression.</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->logTime;?></td>
                <td>What I am feelings are symptoms of illness. I am not making this up</td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>

            <?php else : ?>
            <tr>
                <td>No records found.</td>

            </tr>

            <?php endif;?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: put the var_dump($query) to see what it retrieves from database.

Comment: What does "does not seem to be working" mean?  What's "not working"?  Do you see any errors?  Are you seeing the wrong data?  Does your computer set on fire?  What does this code do that it shouldn't / not do that it should?  "Not working" doesn't help anyone, you need to tell us *what* isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$query->results()` is not a function in CodeIgniter.  It should be `$query->result()`, no `'s'`.

Also, in your view file:

```
<?php if(isset($logs)): foreach($logs as $row);?>
```

The semicolon (`;`), should be a colon (`:`):

```
<?php if(isset($logs)): foreach($logs as $row):?>
```